# JavaScript - calculate Checkbox ONLY when checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked

Im a Javascript beginner, but I have built a simple Cost Estimator for my site using Javascript math functions.

```
function calc(form) {
    a = eval(form.a.value)
    b = eval(form.b.value)
    c = eval(form.c.value)
    x = a*(b+c)
    form.ans.value = parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}
```

The form is simple:

```
<form name="formx">
    <label for="a">Number of Units :</label>
    <input type="number" size=3 value=0 name="a">
    <label for="b">Price per Unit :</label>
    <select name="b">
        <option value="0.04">0.04</option>
        <option value="0.05">0.05</option>
        <option value="0.06">0.06</option>
    </select>
    <label for="c">Tick if Urgent</label>
    <input name="c" type="checkbox" value="0.01" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="  CALCULATE  " onClick="calc(this.form)">
    <label for="ans">Total Cost :</label>
    <input value=" £ " name="ans" size=6>
</form>
```

The "c" value, for Urgent Service, is 0.01, BUT it needs to be added **ONLY** when the checkbox is checked, otherwise its value MUST be 0. But I can't seem to figure it out, because it is always adding "c" value as 0.01, checked or unchecked.

Please help

Answer (score 4):

Try this-

```
function calc(form) {
    var a = parseFloat(form.a.value)
    var b = parseFloat(form.b.value)
    var c = (form.c.checked) ? parseFloat(form.c.value) : 0;
    var x=a*(b+c)
    form.ans.value=parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}
```

**Note** -

## `eval` is evil

From Douglas Crockford's website - [JavaScript Code conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

> The eval function is the most misused feature of JavaScript. Avoid it.
>
> eval has aliases. Do not use the Function constructor. Do not pass
>   strings to setTimeout or setInterval.

Also, read this-

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Radio Buttons instead of Checkboxes. Then you can have multiple values linked to a single object. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp for the exact diffrences